# Formatting legend text font

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I am using this code to plot a graph, and I am trying to make the font of the legend bigger.

```
<<PlotLegends`
ListLogLogPlot[{Sort[moby]}, PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> True, 
    PlotLegend -> {"Moby Dick"}, LegendPosition -> {0.30, -0.20}, LegendShadow -> None, 
    LegendBorder -> None, PlotStyle -> {Dashed}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

This only seems to change the font size of the labels on my axis. But I also want the legend to be size 14.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using `Style` in the option values for `PlotLegend->{...}`. For example:

```
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegend -> {Style["sine", Red, Bold, 18], "cosine"},  
  LegendLabel -> None]
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to do the same thing for all entries in the legend at once, you think? I have a plot with five function in the same graph, and there must be a simpler way than using `Style` five times.

Answer (score 7):

In case you have multiple legends, just use an explicit pure function:

```
PlotLegend -> Style[#, Red, Bold, 18] & /@ {"apple", "pear", "grape"}
```

Comment: minor comment - you need to use PlotLegends after v9 and wrap the above pure function in ( )'s or else you get an error ie, PlotLegends -> ( Style[#, Red, Bold, 18] & /@ {"apple", "pear", "grape"} )

Answer (score 0):

Use LabelStyle to format automatic legends, which will affect legends only and will not affect frame labels and title, for them use respective thread@style, while BaseStyle have no affect at all on any of them,  for example:

```
...
PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, 
  Brown}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 
   7}, ImageSize -> 800, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> 
 Thread@Style[{"q", "SK KT NS SF"}, 
   7], FrameTicks -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 
 2/4, PlotLabel -> 
 Pane[Thread@
   Style[{"SK", "KT", "NS", "SF"}, {Red, Blue, Green, Brown}, 7], 500,
   Alignment -> Center], PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"
```