# LabelStyle doesn't affect PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the default font for PlotLegends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15649/setting-the-default-font-for-plotlegends)

Using version 9

The option setting for `LabelStyle` in plots (I've tried this in `Plot[]`, `DateListPlot[]`, and `ListLinePlot[]`) doesn't appear to affect `PlotLegends[]` at least the way I've tried it:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"), 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos"}]

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"), 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "Cos", LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue")}]
```

Both sets of code give the exact (to an eye) output:

[image]

Note the legend font remains in some default (TimesNewRoman) setting, where everything else in the plot properly goes to "Helvetica Neue".

I've also tried wrapping `Style[]` around each of the legend names to no avail.

Any thoughts on how to do this or work around it?

---

I stumbled upon a workaround, but it doesn't seem very elegant to me so I remain open to other solutions:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"), 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{"Sin", 
    "Cos"}, {LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue")}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to ask, does it work within `LineLegend`?  I assume from you update it does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard --  Yep, works with `LineLegend` too.  Still can't think of a way to do it more directly.

Comment: How about `PlotLegends -> (Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"] & /@ {"Sin", "Cos"})`?

Comment: The syntax description for `PlotLegends` suggests to me that there are no sub-options. The canonical way to style the legends would be to use one of the four xxLegend legends: *The following legend constructors can be used to form commonly occurring legends: SwatchLegend, LineLegend, PointLegend, and BarLegend.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- That works nicely, but one would think that we would have a more direct and simpler way to do it.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries -- Yes, that seems like the most versatile way to do it.  Sometimes, with questions like this, I feel like I can't quite think in the paradigm that the developer did.  We, as a community, can usually come to it, I just wish they made the idea behind how they do specific things clearer in the documentation.   This could just apply me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15649/5

Comment: @rm-rf -- I missed that one.  I'd like to have my answer over there.  I know how you usually feel about merges, but sine mine is the only one would you feel differently?  ( Yes, I like testing the water; again. :o) )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Although that question answers this one, your answer doesn't answer that one, since the OP there wants a global solution, not a local one (see comment under top answer: "But I am interested in changing the default font, not the font of the individual legend instance."). I guess you could merge, to provide an alternate in case someone was satisfied with a local solution, but note that you'll lose the accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no other answers are forthcoming, I have used a syntax like this in other places:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"] & /@ {"Sin", "Cos"})
]
```