# Line style thickness differences between Mathematica 9 and 10

Tags: plotting, version-10

I execute the same code in Mathematica 9 and MAthematica 10, and have this different results.

```
Expr1 = -0.7 alfa + 2;
Expr2 = 1.2 alfa + 1.3;

p2 = Plot[{Expr1, Expr2}, {alfa, 0, 1}, 
  BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[9], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1.5]
Solve[Expr1 == Expr2, alfa]
```

What options I have use to obtaining in Mathematica10 the same results as en Math9.0

Thickness, and colors series.

[image]

Comment: Please remember that folks like to have code to copy/paste -- it's convenient for those who would help you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 , ok. I´m agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue arises due to the introduction of `PlotTheme` in Mma v10.
You can disable this behaviour by using `PlotTheme -> None`, e.g.

```
Plot[{x^2 + x, x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], PlotTheme -> None]
```

If you have multiple plots in your notebook, than you can execute

```
$PlotTheme=None;
```

somewhere before the plots to get the old behaviour for all plots.

---

To get a "Detailed" plot with the "Classic" colors and thicker lines:

```
Plot[{x^2+x,x^2},{x,-1,1},PlotStyle->AbsoluteThickness[4],PlotTheme->{"Detailed","Classic"}]
```

Comment: +1 Well, gee, you'd think specific options would override `Automatic` ones (default `$PlotTheme` is `Automatic`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 the hole `PlotTheme` concept seems to be not yet fully integrated. E.g., Some examples in the documentation are broken now and some easy modifications now even don't work after setting `PlotTheme -> None` [BoxWhiskerChart](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/292539?p_p_auth=5rBmfXri).

Comment: I like the "Detailed" option but... how could I obtain DETAILED with the lines more thickness?, and with the old colors?. CODE p2 = Plot[{Expr1, Expr2}, {p, 0, 1}, 
  BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], PlotTheme -> Detailed]

Comment: @MikaIke try `Plot[{Expr1, Expr2}, {p, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> 
 AbsoluteThickness[4], PlotTheme -> {"Classic", "Detailed"}]`

Comment: @Karsten7. Simply, Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to load '$PlotTheme=None;' into the 'Private Style Definitions', such that I don't need to evaluate this additional cell before evaluating my plots?

Comment: @LBogaardt see the answers to this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15649/18476).

Comment: @Karsten 7. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with style sheets to deduce the method from those answers. Under what style name would 'PlotTheme' fall?

Comment: @LBogaardt If you go to your `$UserBaseDirectory`->Kernel, you can open the init.m and put `$PlotTheme=None` where it says `(** User Mathematica initialization file **)`. This will set the `PlotTheme` to `None` for all notebooks.

Comment: @LBogaardt An other option would be to mark the input cell `$PlotTheme = None;` in your notebook, then right click on the mark and then left click on "Initialization Cell". You will no more need to evaluate this cell before your plots, as it will be evaluated before the first evaluation of an input cell.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than turning off the Theme capability you could work with it:

```
Plot[{x^2 + x, x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines"]
```

[image]

You can combine Themes allowing additional control.  To learn how to create new Themes such as `"Thick5"` see the **Advanced** section of my answer to:

- [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121)

Example of use:

```
Plot[{x^2 + x, x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Thick5"}]
```

[image]