# Formatting legend text font multiple times

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the same question as asked in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/formatting-legend-text-font) question. With the difference that I want to change multiple legend entries.

I tried:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {j, 2}, {i, 10}],
PlotLegends -> Style[#, Small] & /@ {"first entry", "second entry"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ListLinePlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {j, 2}, {i, 10}], 
 PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"first entry", "second entry"})]
```

with the effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much, but why does Small not work here?

Comment: Ah ok, I see it is not the Small vs. specific number but the brackets.

Comment: Yeah, it's the precedence of `&` vs `->`. The former has a pretty low precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it.

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {j, 2}, {i, 10}], 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"first entry", "second entry"}, LabelStyle -> Small]]
```

[image: plot]